# I was sold a cactus

Tags: grammar

Can "sell" be used in this passive structure meaning that that cactus was sold to me?

> My sister is curious to know what was sold to me for the New Year, so I reply to her, "I was sold a wondrous cactus, having sharpy spikes."

Comment: Did someone _sell_ the cactus to you, or give it as a New Year present?

Comment: By "I was sold a cactus", I mean that someone sold it to me. Is my passive structure with "sell" grammatically correct?

Comment: "A cactus was sold to me" is a passive-voice construction (from the active "X sold a cactus to me") but "I was sold a cactus" is not the same.

Comment: **Do not answer in comments.** Write an answer. Comments are there to ask for more details or counter misapprehensions in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can say "I was sold [something]", but if you went to a shop to choose it, it would be more natural to say "I bought [something]". Using the passive voice of *to sell* puts the responsibility on the seller. You might say "I was sold a stale loaf" if you were blaming the baker for supplying you with bread that wasn't fresh.

Comment: Yep. *I was sold a bill of goods* tells you those goods were not. Though *I was sold at once* is good.

Answer (score 2):

*The Grammar Book - An ESL /EFL Teacher's Course*  section on ditransitive verbs (p371) notes that:
:

> English has more passive voice alternatives than some other languages
> do. Thus the active voice sentence *Alice gave John the book* has two
> passive voice paraphrases. One option selects the direct object as the
> subject of the passive:
>
> - The book was given to John (by Alice).
>
> The other option selects the indirect object as the subject of the
> passive:
>
> - John was given the book (by Alice).

Your sentence *I was sold a cactus* is a close equivalent to the *John was given the book* second passive option above.

It may be useful to mention here, however, that *The Grammar Book* notes that not all ditransitive verbs can be passivised as in the second option to produce sentences that are fully acceptable to native speakers.

It lists, for example, the transformation of *Arlene made Sandra a dress* into the questionable *?Arlene was made a dress by Sandra*.

*The Grammar Book* concludes that this is an area of grammar that needs further research in order to "*help us determine which verbs allow indirect object alternation and which do not.*"

Answer (score 0):

> *I reply to her, "I was sold a wondrous cactus, having sharpy spikes."*

**Wondrous** is inappropriate unless the cactus possesses magical powers. The word is also very dated. There is nothing "wondrous" about a cactus with spikes.

**The passive use of "sold"** implies that the person selling it convinced you to buy it (i) against your will or (ii) against your better judgement, (iii) despite your having no intention of buying anything or, as Kate Bunting suggests, (iv) you now feel cheated.

**"having sharpy spikes"** is an unnatural/non-idiomatic use of a participle phrase.

**"sharpy"** is an interesting adjective - it does not appear in major dictionaries but it has a certain humour to it.